# Opening especifique layout from local notification in IOS with Titanium

Tags: ios, titanium, localnotification

I'm showing som notifications that are created inside of a service. But when I click on the notification I wold like to open an specific layout. How can I due that?

This is my notification:

```
var curNotif = Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
            alertBody : 'bg-service2: has been invoked ' + not + ' times. It is still registered and will run again when the app is transitioned to the background',
            date : new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000) // 1 second after pause
        });
```

My project only has one window that is created in the app.js. Then I create view with my layout and add or remove them from the same window.

Comment: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/NotificationParams, you also try to pass JSON object in `userInfo` and that you can get when you receive the notification and on the basis of that data you can easily write code for redirection.

Comment: can you poste an example code please?